# How to remove corrupt RPM install

Tags: rpm

I tried to install an RPM package and the install process failed. It looks like the program needs signing the Kernel Modules or something. Now I'm stuck in a weird state where rpm says the package is installed, but when I try to uninstall it, it claims it's not installed.

```
sudo rpm -i mypackage.rpm
    package mypackage is already installed

sudo rpm -e mypackage.rpm
error: package mypackage is not installed
```

How can I resolve the install/uninstall state? I'd like to remove the package.

Comment: I've tried to keep the question as generic as possible, the rpm package in question is VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.12_139181_fedora32-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Try uninstalling the package using `sudo rpm -e VirtualBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpm -e` requires a *package* name, not a filename.

And anyway you should use `dnf` to install and remove packages, for consistency. It should be quite a rare event if you have to use `rpm` itself.

Answer (score 0):

other way of doing it is to use

```
rpm -qa | grep package_name
```

It will give you full package name and then you can use

```
rpm -e package_name
```

to delete it.